# TextCallbackHandler password issue

Tags: java, jaas

I'm trying to do some tutorials for JAAS and bumped into a weird issue. When I do in my IDE, everything works fine and I'm asked both for username and password

```
LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("JaasSample", new TextCallbackHandler());
lc.login();
```

But if I run the same class from a jar, I'm only asked for username and then I immediately get an exception (not being asked for a password):

```
    [vmuser@VMServer1 jaasacn]$ sh run.sh 
    Kerberos username [vmuser]: user1 
Kerberos password for user1: Authentication failed:   
Security Exception 
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Security Exception
                at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:848)
                at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203)
                at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690)
                at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687)
                at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595)
                at JaasAcn.main(JaasAcn.java:29) Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException
                at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:849)
                ... 7 more
```

What could be an issue?!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact problem and exception when I tried to login from an Application deployed in Jboss. The jaas login module worked fine when I ran it from IDE, but it failed when it was running in Jboss. After some research, I found out that the actual jaas.config file is being ignored, and the only way to configure a Jaas module was with Jboss standalone.xml file (in my case). After I declared the module in standalone.xml, then everything worked as expected.

Anyway, it took me some time to figure out what was with that Security Exception.

There must be some configuration issues in your case also.. I hope this helped